# Error al visualizar la carga de horario de clases

Tags: php, pdo

Saludos tengo un problema a la hora de mostrar los registro en mi horario de clases siempre me muestra este error en el array:

```
Warning: Undefined array key 2
Warning: Undefined array key 3
Warning: Undefined array key 4
etc
```

donde me hace referencia al tercer for con el if.

```
<table width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#E3E9F1">
                <tr>
                  <td width="126" bgcolor="#C4D2E2"><div align="center"><strong>hora </strong></div></td>
                  <td width="126" bgcolor="#C4D2E2"><div align="center"><strong>Lunes</strong></div></td>
                  <td width="126" bgcolor="#C4D2E2"><div align="center"><strong>Martes</strong></div></td>
                  <td width="126" bgcolor="#C4D2E2"><div align="center"><strong>Miercoles</strong></div></td>
                  <td width="126" bgcolor="#C4D2E2"><div align="center"><strong>Jueves</strong></div></td>
                  <td width="130" bgcolor="#C4D2E2"><div align="center"><strong>Viernes</strong></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#E1E1E1" class="letra8"><div align="center">07:00-07:40 </div></td>
                  <td  height="35" colspan="6" rowspan="17" class="letra8">


<?php
$consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT 
horario_semestre.id_horario_semestre,
horario_semestre.id_trayecto,
horario_semestre.id_horario_academico,
horario_semestre.id_pnf,
horario_semestre.id_horas_de_clases,
horario_semestre.id_dias_de_la_semana,
horario_semestre.id_aula,
horario_semestre.id_materias,
horario_semestre.id_usuarios,
trayecto.id_trayecto,
trayecto.trayecto,
horario_academico.id_horario_academico,
horario_academico.horario_academico,
pnf.id_pnf,
pnf.pnf,
horas_de_clases.id_horas_de_clases,
horas_de_clases.horas_de_clases,
dias_de_la_semana.id_dias_de_la_semana,
dias_de_la_semana.dias_de_la_semana,
aula.id_aula,
aula.aula,
materias.id_materias,
materias.materias,
usuarios.id_usuarios,
usuarios.nombres,
usuarios.apellidos,
nivel.id_nivel,
nivel.nivel
FROM horario_semestre
INNER JOIN trayecto ON horario_semestre.id_trayecto=trayecto.id_trayecto 
INNER JOIN horario_academico ON horario_semestre.id_horario_academico=horario_academico.id_horario_academico
INNER JOIN pnf ON horario_semestre.id_pnf=pnf.id_pnf
INNER JOIN horas_de_clases ON horario_semestre.id_horas_de_clases=horas_de_clases.id_horas_de_clases
INNER JOIN dias_de_la_semana ON horario_semestre.id_dias_de_la_semana=dias_de_la_semana.id_dias_de_la_semana
INNER JOIN aula ON horario_semestre.id_aula=aula.id_aula
INNER JOIN materias ON horario_semestre.id_materias=materias.id_materias
INNER JOIN usuarios ON horario_semestre.id_usuarios=usuarios.id_usuarios
INNER JOIN nivel ON usuarios.id_nivel=nivel.nivel 
WHERE nivel.nivel='Docente';");
$dias = array();
$num='65';# Es el resultado de: columnas * filas donde muestro las materias.
while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
       
        $d[] = $linea['dias_de_la_semana']; 
        $h[] = $linea['horas_de_clases']; 
        $mat[] = $linea['materias'];
        $aul[] = $linea['aula'];
        $nom[] = $linea['nombres'];
        $ape[] = $linea['apellidos'];            
    }   


echo "<table width='750'height='20' border='1'align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#E3E9F1'id='tabla'>"; 

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 13; $i++) { // Crea las 13 filas
            echo "<tr width='90' height='30'>"; 
           
            for ($j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++) { // Crea las 5 columnas 
                echo "<td width='100'align='center'>";
               


                for ($k = 0; $k < $num; $k++) 
                   
                   {     
                    
                    if ($d[$k] == $j && $h[$k] == $i) { 

                         echo $mat[$k]."<br>".$aul[$k]." - ".$nom[$k]." ".$ape[$k];

                         
                   }    
                } 



            echo "</td>"; 
             } 
          echo "</tr>"; 
       } 
   echo "</table>"; 
?>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">07:20 - 08:05</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">08:05 - 08:50</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">08:55 - 09:40</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">09:40 - 10:25</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">10:30 - 11:15</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">11:15 - 12:00</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#FFFFE1"><div align="center">------------</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">01:00 - 01:45</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">01:45 - 02:30</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">02:35 - 03:20</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">03:20 - 04:05</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">04:10 - 04:55</div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#66CCFF" class="letra8">
                  <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">04:55 - 05:40</div></td>
                </tr>
           
              </table>
```

Comment: Hay un mal planteamiento en ese problema. Después del `while` has un `var_dump($mat);` a ver cuantos registros trae ¿Qué garantía hay de que esa consulta traerá 65 (o más) resultados? Los ciclos `for` anidados intentarán imprimir todos los resultados (65 veces) dentro de cada `<td></td>`. En otras palabras se imprimirán un total de 4265 veces. Se debe dibujar la tabla dinámicamente dependiendo de los registros devueltos por la consulta, y lo más usual es que esto se haga dentro del ciclo `while`.

Comment: Hola hice un ´´´var_dump($mat);, aul y nom´´´ y el array me lo devuelve perfectamente: que son los tres registros es están guardados en la tabla.  array(3) { [0]=> string(30) "PROYECTO SOCIO TECNOLÓGICO IV" [1]=> string(37) "PROYECTO NACIONAL Y NUEVA CIUDADANÍA" [2]=> string(10) "ELECTIVA I" }
array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "LAB-06" [1]=> string(6) "LAB-01" [2]=> string(5) "A-112" }
array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "SOBEIDA" [1]=> string(13) "IRAIDES JOSÉ" [2]=> string(4) "JUAN" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado es un ejemplo mira primero crea una vista y asi sacas ese query tan largo

```
CREATE VIEW vista_horario_docentes AS
SELECT 
    horario_semestre.id_horario_semestre, horario_semestre.id_trayecto, horario_semestre.id_horario_academico, horario_semestre.id_pnf,
    horario_semestre.id_horas_de_clases, horario_semestre.id_dias_de_la_semana, horario_semestre.id_aula, horario_semestre.id_materias, 
    horario_semestre.id_usuarios, trayecto.id_trayecto, trayecto.trayecto, horario_academico.id_horario_academico, horario_academico.horario_academico,
    pnf.id_pnf, pnf.pnf, horas_de_clases.id_horas_de_clases, horas_de_clases.horas_de_clases, dias_de_la_semana.id_dias_de_la_semana,
    dias_de_la_semana.dias_de_la_semana, aula.id_aula, aula.aula, materias.id_materias, materias.materias, usuarios.id_usuarios, usuarios.nombres,
    usuarios.apellidos, nivel.id_nivel, nivel.nivel
FROM horario_semestre
INNER JOIN trayecto ON horario_semestre.id_trayecto=trayecto.id_trayecto 
INNER JOIN horario_academico ON horario_semestre.id_horario_academico=horario_academico.id_horario_academico
INNER JOIN pnf ON horario_semestre.id_pnf=pnf.id_pnf
INNER JOIN horas_de_clases ON horario_semestre.id_horas_de_clases=horas_de_clases.id_horas_de_clases
INNER JOIN dias_de_la_semana ON horario_semestre.id_dias_de_la_semana=dias_de_la_semana.id_dias_de_la_semana
INNER JOIN aula ON horario_semestre.id_aula=aula.id_aula
INNER JOIN materias ON horario_semestre.id_materias=materias.id_materias
INNER JOIN usuarios ON horario_semestre.id_usuarios=usuarios.id_usuarios
INNER JOIN nivel ON usuarios.id_nivel=nivel.nivel 
WHERE nivel.nivel='Docente';
```

y después solo la llamas por la vista creada **vista_horario_docentes**

```
    <table width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#E3E9F1">
        <tr>
          <td width="126" bgcolor="#C4D2E2"><div align="center"><strong>hora </strong></div></td>
          <td width="126" bgcolor="#C4D2E2"><div align="center"><strong>Lunes</strong></div></td>
          <td width="126" bgcolor="#C4D2E2"><div align="center"><strong>Martes</strong></div></td>
          <td width="126" bgcolor="#C4D2E2"><div align="center"><strong>Miercoles</strong></div></td>
          <td width="126" bgcolor="#C4D2E2"><div align="center"><strong>Jueves</strong></div></td>
          <td width="130" bgcolor="#C4D2E2"><div align="center"><strong>Viernes</strong></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="13" bgcolor="#E1E1E1" class="letra8"><div align="center">07:00-07:40 </div></td>
          <td  height="35" colspan="6" rowspan="17" class="letra8">
    <?php
    $sql="SELECT * FROM vista_horario_docentes;
    
    $consulta = $DB_con->query($sql);
    $consult_fetch=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    $horario = array_fill(1, 13, array_fill(1, 5, ''));
    $lista = ['dias_de_la_semana', 'horas_de_clases', 'materias', 'aula', 'nombres', 'apellidos'];
    
    foreach ($consulta as $consult_fetch) {
        list($d, $h, $mat, $aul, $nom, $ape) = array_map(fn($item) => $consult_fetch[$item], $lista);
        
        if ($d >= 1 && $d <= 5 && $h >= 1 && $h <= 13) {
            $horario[$h][$d] .= "$mat<br>$aul - $nom $ape<br>";
        }
    }
    
    ?>
    <table width='750' height='20' border='1' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#E3E9F1' id='tabla'>
    <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 13; $i++) {
            ?>
            <tr width='90' height='30'>
            <?php
            for ($j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++) {
                echo "<td width='100' align='center'>" . $horario[$i][$j] . "</td>";
            }
            ?>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
    </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
<?php
$horarios = ["07:20 - 08:05","08:05 - 08:50","08:55 - 09:40","09:40 - 10:25","10:30 - 11:15","11:15 - 12:00","------------","01:00 - 01:45","01:45 - 02:30","02:35 - 03:20","03:20 - 04:05","04:10 - 04:55","04:55 - 05:40"];

foreach ($horarios as $horario) {
    $bgcolor = ($horario === "------------") ? "#FFFFE1" : "#F8F8F8";
    echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bgcolor . '" class="letra8">';
   ?>
   <td height="13" bgcolor="#F8F8F8"><div align="center">
   <?php
   echo $horario;
   ?>
   </div></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
}
?>


 </table>
```

es solo un ejemplo, espero te sea de utilidad.

cambie varias cosas para poder hacerlo mas simple

Comment: hola John probé tu ejemplo y funciona, pero también modifique el código que puse y me funciono, pero ahora mi gran problema es que no se me cuadra la parte visual ósea me queda todo descuadrado y por mas que intento no logro que me quede bien cuadrado te anexo una imagen para que me puedas entender mejor

Comment: Aquí la imagen: https://ibb.co/16DpJSV de verdad que es la primera vez que intento hacer esto y es muy difícil lograr que cuadre

Comment: entiendo, el problema es de forma mas que de código, no pongas tablas dentro de tablas, hace una sola tabla para que todo cuadre.   mi consejo es que armes la tabla con datos ficticios sin extraer de la base, y una ves que se vea bien, allí si empiezas a colocar los datos de la base

Comment: listo pude adaptar tu código con algunas mejoras y me sirvió muchas gracias estoy muy agradecido